# Unwind not working on one project but does on another

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Something strange it's happening to my current code. I'm performing a Unwind (Exit) to the Main View Controller of a UINavigationController and does not work, But I've done the exact same steps on a new project and it works perfect. Does any One have a General Idea of why Xcode Behaves different? event sometimes the Application does not perform the actions it should even if the code its 100% good, and then all of the sudden all works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your workflow is correct. Sometimes assumption about navigation stack is incorrect and unwind is impossible.

Comment: thanks, but I've check check double check everything properly and it does not give any errors. Simply does not execute the IBACtion containing the storyboardSegue for the unwind. it is properly connected to the exit and has the segue identifier and its being called with the name it has on the unwind but nothing happens :/

Comment: Do you mean that prepare for segue method is working? If yes, have you already found segue destination controller? Is it your desired class or nil?